# Verify user identity on my site, using SSL Certificates

Tags: authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to register companies on my site for an electronic procurement system. Up to now these were local companies I could meet physically and give credentials to, but now they can be companies based anywhere in the world.

The solution is to have an online registration process whereby they submit a third party certificate. So say Verisign says they are 'Company X' so I register them as Company X and issue them credentials.

How can I implement this on my site? Do I simply give them a field in the registration form where they upload their certificate file? Do I then manually check these certificates in my back office? How does one check this manually? Is there a way to automate this process?

Once they have an account, should I simply request the credentials I issue them with to log in, or can all future logins request the same certificate file? In these a particular format for certificates I can request or should I allow a number of common formats that different certificate vendors provide?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of certificate are you asking about? Why would anybody give you their ssl certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to provide a certificate does unfortunately not prove anything. A certificate is completely public, and anyone can get a hold of the SSL certificate for any website. The certificate contains a public key. Proving ownership of the corresponding private key is what's required.

This is possible to do, but it requires that your users are technical enough to know how to run scripts and/or OpenSSL terminal commands so that they can sign something with their private key. Having the users upload their private key is of course a big no-no, as it means you can now act as the user, and that would require an enormous amount of trust in you to discard the private key after you've verified it.

From a technical perspective, you can do the verification by creating some kind of challenge, for example a random string, and have the user encrypt this string with their private key. If you decrypt this string with the public key in the certificate, and get the original string back, then you know that they have possession of the corresponding private key.

Here's a self-contained Ruby script that demonstrates this, with comments indicating which part of it is run on your side, and which part is run on their side.

```ruby
require "openssl"

## This happens on the client side. They generate a private key and a certificate.
## This particular certificate is not signed by a CA - it is assumed that a CA
## signature  check is already done elsewhere on the user cert.

user_keypair = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)


user_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
user_cert.not_before = Time.now
user_cert.subject = OpenSSL::X509::Name.new([
    ["C", "NO"],
    ["ST", "Oslo"],
    ["L", "Oslo"],
    ["CN", "August Lilleaas"]
  ])
user_cert.issuer = user_cert.subject
user_cert.not_after = Time.now + 1000000000 # 40 or so years
user_cert.public_key = user_keypair.public_key
user_cert.sign(user_keypair, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new)

File.open("/tmp/user-cert.crt", "w+") do |f|
  f.write user_cert.to_pem
end


## This happens on your side - generate a random phrase, and agree on a digest algorithm

random_phrase = "A small brown fox"

digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new

## The client signs (encrypts a cheksum) the random phrase

signature = user_keypair.sign(digest, random_phrase)


## On your side, verify the signature using the user's certificate.

your_user_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.new("/tmp/user-cert.crt"))
puts your_user_cert.public_key.verify(digest, signature, random_phrase + "altered")
# => falase
puts your_user_cert.public_key.verify(digest, signature, random_phrase)
# => true

## On your side - attempting to verify with another public key/keypair fails

malicious_keypair = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)
puts malicious_keypair.public_key.verify(digest, signature, random_phrase)
```

Note that this script does not take into account the CA verification step - you  also obviously want to verify that the user's certificate is verified by a CA, such as Verisign that you mentioned, because anyone can issue a certificate and hold a private key for foo.com - it's the CA signature of the certificate that provides authenticity guarantees.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe a way to make the challenge step more feasible would be to actually provide a simple downloadable utility on the site which does the above when given a challenge string and a private key? 

So the client registers in 2 steps. 

1. Fill in info fields, and is given a challenge, downloads the program, selects his private key on his system and

2. Upload the public key and the enctypted challenge?

The target is companies which will usually have IT staff, so I think it would be workable so long as they understand how to get their own public and private key.

Comment: Yeah, signing the challenge with the private key can definitely be GUI-ized. The ruby code is just an interface to the standard OpenSSL library, so the functionality is available in pretty much any language/platform. The only issue is that they would have to trust your program not to upload their private key to your server or something obnoxious, so I would recommend also providing an alternate "manual" method by either a simple ruby script like in my answer, or by some example OpenSSL CLI commands.

Comment: I would also recommend that you generate the challenge on your end, and not have the client side utility generate it. That way you can control that the challenge is sufficiently long and unique.